# I Want To Remove GROUP BY From My Query As It Interferes With The Output

Tags: php, mysql

Good day,

Please I sincerely don't know how to write sub-queries and I need help with that. I discovered that GROUP BY in the query I will post below is interfering with the pagination of the page. Can someone help me re-write the query to exclude GROUP BY?

```
$select = "SELECT report.id AS id, COUNT(reportUserName) AS reportCount, "
        . " branchName, reportDate";
$from = " FROM report INNER JOIN branches"; 
$where = " WHERE report.branchUserName = branches.branchUserName GROUP BY reportDate, "
        . "report.branchUserName";
```

Here is the code that should create the pagination

```
if (isset($_POST['items_per_page']) && is_numeric($_POST['items_per_page']))
    $_SESSION['items_per_page'] = $_POST['items_per_page'];
  
    $conn = DatabaseManager::getConnection();
    //get the function
    include_once ('../function.php');

        $page = (int) (!isset($_GET["page"]) ? 1 : $_GET["page"]);
        
    $limit = $pageNo;

if (isset($_SESSION['items_per_page']) && is_numeric($_SESSION['items_per_page']))
$limit = intval($_SESSION['items_per_page']);
  
  
        $startpoint = ($page * $limit) - $limit;
        
        //to make pagination
        $statement = "report INNER JOIN branches WHERE report.branchUserName = branches.branchUserName GROUP BY reportDate, report.branchUserName";

$select = "SELECT report.id AS id, COUNT(reportUserName) AS reportCount, "
        . " branchName, reportDate";
$from = " FROM report INNER JOIN branches"; 
$where = " WHERE report.branchUserName = branches.branchUserName GROUP BY reportDate, report.branchUserName";
    
    
            try
                {
                    $sql = $select . $from . $where . " ORDER BY serviceDate DESC LIMIT {$startpoint} , {$limit}";
                    $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
                    $query->execute();
                }
            catch (PDOException $e)
                {
                    $error[] = 'Error performing the operation you wanted.';
                }
```

Here is function.php used in the code above

```
function pagination($query, $per_page = 10, $page = 1, $url = '?'){ 
   include_once ('classes/DatabaseManager.php'); 
   $conn = DatabaseManager::getConnection();
           
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT report.reportUserName) as `num` FROM {$query}";
        foreach($conn->query($query) as $row);
        $total = $row['num'];
        $adjacents = "2"; 
        
    //Ronald's code begings
    $url = '?';
        foreach($_GET as $k => $v) {
        if($k != 'page') {
        $url .= "{$k}={$v}&";
          }
        }
        //Ronald's code ends

        $page = ($page == 0 ? 1 : $page);  
        $start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;                               
        
        $prev = $page - 1;                          
        $next = $page + 1;
        $lastpage = ceil($total/$per_page);
        $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;
        
        $pagination = "";
        if($lastpage > 1)
        {   
            $pagination .= "<ul class='pagination'>";
                $pagination .= "<li class='details'>Page $page of $lastpage</li>";
            if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))
            {   
                for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>$counter</a></li>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";                    
                }
            }
            elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))
            {
                if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))        
                {
                    for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
                    {
                        if ($counter == $page)
                            $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>$counter</a></li>";
                        else
                            $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";                    
                    }
                    $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>...</li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$lpm1'>$lpm1</a></li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$lastpage'>$lastpage</a></li>";      
                }
                elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
                {
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=1'>1</a></li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=2'>2</a></li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>...</li>";
                    for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
                    {
                        if ($counter == $page)
                            $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>$counter</a></li>";
                        else
                            $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";                    
                    }
                    $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>..</li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$lpm1'>$lpm1</a></li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$lastpage'>$lastpage</a></li>";      
                }
                else
                {
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=1'>1</a></li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=2'>2</a></li>";
                    $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>..</li>";
                    for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                    {
                        if ($counter == $page)
                            $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>$counter</a></li>";
                        else
                            $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$counter'>$counter</a></li>";                    
                    }
                }
            }
            
            if ($page < $counter - 1){ 
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$next'>Next</a></li>";
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}page=$lastpage'>Last</a></li>";
            }else{
                $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>Next</a></li>";
                $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>Last</a></li>";
            }
            $pagination.= "</ul>\n";        
        }
    
    
        return $pagination;
    }
```

Here is the sample data

```
-- version 5.0.4
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Feb 23, 2021 at 11:53 AM
-- Server version: 10.4.17-MariaDB
-- PHP Version: 7.4.14

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `mydata`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `report`
--

CREATE TABLE `report` (
  `id` bigint(50) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `branchUserName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `reportUserName` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `reportDate` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `report`
--

INSERT INTO `report` (`id`, `branchUserName`, `reportUserName`, `reportDate`) VALUES
(6, 'marketing', 'marketing-jan-10', 2020-10-5),
(7, 'marketing', 'marketing-nov-19', 2020-9-24),
(8, 'production', 'production-nov-16', 2020-12-27),
(9, 'production', 'production-feb-14', 2020-12-27),
(13, 'production', 'production-feb-14', 2020-8-17);

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `report`
--
ALTER TABLE `report`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `reportUN` (`reportUserName`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `report`
--
ALTER TABLE `report`
  MODIFY `id` bigint(50) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=14;
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

The other table

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 5.0.4
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Feb 23, 2021 at 11:53 AM
-- Server version: 10.4.17-MariaDB
-- PHP Version: 7.4.14

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `mydata`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `branches`
--

CREATE TABLE `branches` (
  `id` int(15) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `branchUserName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `branchStatus` varchar(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `branches`
--

INSERT INTO `branches` (`id`, `branchUserName`, `branchStatus`) VALUES
(3,  'marketing',  'Active'),
(7,  'production', 'Active'),
(10, 'packaking', 'Active');

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `branches`
--
ALTER TABLE `branches`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `branches`
--
ALTER TABLE `branches`
  MODIFY `id` int(15) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=11;
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

The two tables involved are here. The result gets displayed correctly, the ONLY PROBLEM is that the pagination is not working. The result gets displayed but pagination doesn't get displayed, hence you can't check the second page, you are stucked with only the result on the first page.

Comment: Sample data and expected output would be very helpful here.

Comment: 'f you use an aggregate function in a statement containing no GROUP BY clause, it is equivalent to grouping on all rows.' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, the code above is working fine. I just need a re-write that excludes GROUP BY. There is nothing wrong with the code itself. If I can have a re-written one, I will use that to test my pagination and report the outcome back here. Thank you.

Comment: @P.Salmon, I am checking the link you posted up right away.

Comment: If you're going to use COUNT then you need GROUP BY. So if you're going to remove the GROUP BY, you also need to remove the COUNT. Is that ok in your situation, or not? We don't fully understand what you want instead. That's why Tim asked you to provide some sample data, and the result that you want from your query (based on that sample). Then we can more easily understand exactly what you're aiming for.

Comment: @ADyson, thank you for your response. I simply want reports grouped by the date of the report (reportDate) and report.branchUserName (which is fixed for each of the branch[departments] in the company). I hope the explanation is clearer? The COUNT was introduced so I can know the number of reports received under the branchUserName for each date. If you can help me re-write the SQL to exclude GROUP BY while still giving the same result, that would be great.

Comment: `grouped by the date of the report (reportDate) and report.branchUserName (which is fixed for each of the branch[departments] in the company)`...then you need GROUP BY. There isn't an alternative. And that sounds like exactly the query you have already, so no, it's not any clearer. If you want a different result than you are current getting then please, as requested before, **provide some sample data, and the result that you want from your query (based on that sample)**. We didn't ask that for no reason.

Comment: If you simply do as we ask and show us exactly what you want, then we'll know exactly what you want and what you mean. It's much easier to write a computer program based on an exact specification than a vague description (especially a description which appears to be contradictory, i.e. "make it group the results but don't use group by", which is what you appear to be asking for).

Comment: N.B. referring back to the orignal question, it's worth noting that we also have no idea what "interfering with the pagination of the page" really means. That's also very vague. We know it's having some effect that you don't like, but we don't know what it was like before you had this problem, what the undesirable effect is, how it's implemented, or how it relates to your other stated requirements. Remember we know nothing about your application or your data, and we're not mind-readers.

Comment: @ADyson, thank you very much for this help. I sincerely have a problem on how to share my pagination code here. I am okay with the initial code I shared. It's working fine but because it contains GROUP BY, the pagination simply don't show on the page where it is supposed to which was why I said GROUP BY is interfering with my pagination. Any idea how I can share my pagination function in case that is what the problem is with?

Comment: You can edit your question if you need to include extra code or information.

Comment: Okay, Thank you.

Comment: I have updated the codes.

Comment: So it seems like the "pagination" function uses a count of unique usernames in order to generate the page numbers. But then the query which displays the data groups the data by date. So clearly it won't output the same number of rows. That's why it interferes. The problem is how we solve it? You still haven't explained the contradiction in your requirement - you want a report which doesn't use grouping, but yet the results are still grouped. It still doesn't make sense. You still haven't explained what you actually want in a way that we can understand and is workable.

Comment: So the missing piece of the jigsaw is still the list of sample data and expected results, which you've been asked for 3 times now already - this is the 4th. If you can't/won't provide that, we can't easily help you. Or...maybe the solution is that the pagination function uses the query grouped by date as well? It's unclear, because we don't know what data you actually want to show on your page or what it's supposed to represent.

Comment: @ADyson, sample data added for clarity. Thank you.

Comment: Ok. And what about the current result, and the expected result, please? You were asked for those as well. We _still_ don't know what you actually want. I'm beginning to wonder if you don't know that yourself either.

Comment: `The result gets displayed but pagination doesn't get displayed, hence you can't check the second page`...ok but presumably that's because the data being displayed isn't what you wanted? Or because the pagination doesn't count the rows in the same way as the query does? Again it's unclear what you want. We know what happens currently, but we still don't know exactly how you want it to be resolved.